# How can I change MJ into EU?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-feed-the-beast

I'm using the Yogcraft mod pack in Feed The Beast. How do I change MJ into EU?

Answer (score 1):

The YogCraft mod pack has [power coverters](http://ftbwiki.org/Power_Converters) that allow you to convert one type of power source to another.